# How to register generic JsonDeserializer for all types which implements given interface

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, fasterxml

Does exist any way how to register JSON deserializer for all types which implements particular interface using Jackson 2.X and Spring Framework instead of annotating every property with `@JsonDeserialize(using = IdentifiableDeserializer.class)`?

**Generic deserializer**

```
public class IdentifiableDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<IdentifiableEntity> implements ContextualDeserializer{

    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> createContextual(DeserializationContext ctxt, BeanProperty property)
            throws JsonMappingException {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public IdentifiableEntity deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        // ...
    }

}
```

**Entity which should be deserialized**

```
public class MyEntity implements IdentifiableEntity{
    private Long id;

    public getId(){
        return id;
    }
    //...
}
```

**Serice**

```
@Service("myEntityService")
private MyEntityService implements IdentifiableService<MyEntity>{

    MyEntity findById(Long id){
        //...
    }

}
```

I tried us following approach, but it does not work.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView">
    <property name="objectMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean">
            <property name="deserializersByType">
                <map key-type="java.lang.Class">
                    <entry key="xx.yy.IdentifiableEntity">
                        <bean class="xxx.yyy.IdentifiableDeserializer" />
                    </entry>
                </map>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can take a look at [custom deserializers](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule testModule = new SimpleModule("MyModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null))
   .addDeserializer(IdentifiableEntity.class, new IdentifiableDeserializer());
mapper.registerModule(testModule);
```

Comment: I think this way is almost equivalent to my. I've registered a module but the deserializer was not invoked. I guess that the problem is difference of types. Jackson seeks for the exact type not for `IdentifiableEntity`.

Comment: I don't think so, it should work for subtypes as well. You can try with an exact type nevertheless, just to be sure that it is (or isn't) the issue.

Comment: I've just tried it for subtype and for subtypes it is working as is expected, but if is used the interface `IdentifiableEntity` which implements all entities it does not work.